# What's missing in this for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying to print in the screen this, given any number like 12:

```
0+12
1+11
2+10
3+9
4+8
5+7
6+6 equal!
7+5
8+4
9+3
10+2
11+1
12+0
```

And for that i write the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int number, increment;
    scanf("%d", &number);

    for (increment = 0; increment <= number; increment++)
    {
        if ((increment >= 0) && (increment != number)) printf("%d+%d\n", increment, number);
        else if (increment == number) printf("%d+%d equal\n", increment, number);
        else if (number < increment) printf("%d+%d\n", increment, number);
        number--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And my code's output is:

```
0+12
1+11
2+10
3+9
4+8
5+7
6+6 equal
// missing part!
```

And nothing more.... What thing i need to fix in the loop to show the missing part?

Thanks.

Comment: Put this code in a debugger, learn how to step through it, and you will see the problem in under a minute.  Using a debugger is NOT "optional" in programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you have to make everything so complicated?

```
for(i=0; i <= num; ++i)
{
    printf("%d+%d%s\n", i, num-i, (i == num-i)? " equal" : "");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are checking `increment <= number` and constantly decreasing `number.` You are essentially losing the 12 completely. You can do this instead:

```
for (increment = number; increment >= 0; increment--)
{
    ...
}
```

The loop body will have to be changed accordingly of course.

Comment: I need to change all the variables in the ifs and else ifs?

Comment: Yep. `increment` (which we should probably rename something more appropriately) will now count down from 12 to 0.

Comment: Sorry being a n00b in C, but still don't catch what should I change in the variables.

Comment: The number before the `+` will be `number - increment` and the one after will be `increment`.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are decrementing number and using it a loop control variable which means after you add to increment and take from number it will only loop 6 times not the 12 you think it will.